# I don't know how to write sql query in python by using sqlalchemy.create_engine

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, trading

```
def check_data(self, code):
    if self.is_table_exist():
        sql = "SELECT check_item FROM '%s' WHERE code = '%s'"
        check = self.engine_stock_item_all.execute(sql % (self.today, str(code))).fetchall()[0][0]
        return check

def is_table_exist(self):
    sql = "SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema ='stock_item_all' AND table_name = '{}'"
    rows = self.engine_stock_item_all.execute(sql.format(self.today)).fetchall()
    if rows:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def make_daily_db(self):
    code_name = self.daily_item['code_name']
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.daily_item)
    df_temp = df[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'market_cap', 'volume', 'issued_shares', 'outstanding_shares']]
    df_temp.to_sql(name=code_name, con=self.engine_daily_chart, if_exists='append')
    sql = "UPDATE '%s' SET check_item=1 WHERE code_name = '%s'"
    self.engine_stock_item_all.execute(sql % (self.today, code_name))
```

Hi, now I'm developing trading program in python(3.8). And If I run the program I got error like this.

Error

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064,
> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''20201130' WHERE code = '155660'' at line 1") [SQL: SELECT
> check_item FROM '20201130' WHERE code = '155660']

I debugged my code and I think I do something wrong at a method I defined check_data, is_table_exist and make_daily_db. I try many things to solve this problem all day, but I don't know how to change my code.
Please someone who knows help me. I really need your helps.

Comment: Is the table name literally all numbers? If so, try using back-ticks instead of single quotes: `SELECT check_item FROM \`%s\` WHERE code = '%s'`

Comment: Oh, really thanks for your answer. I try your comment and... I got another error. Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).   I think this is error about PyQt5.EventLoop. If you know this problem please give your help more. Anyway thanks a lot !

Comment: Ok, but the original question about a table name being all numbers was never answered, so my example was only a guess. It appears that the table may not be numbers, causing the error, but I would think the date and code would be in the WHERE clause, and the FROM clause would possibly use `stock_item_all`? ... I could be wrong, but I don't have the full picture that you know.

Comment: I solve the problem. Your comment was really helpful for me. thanks!

Comment: What was the discovery? (could be helpful to others as well)

Comment: It was not a big problem. I had an error at casting

Answer (score 0):

Remove single Quotes

```
SELECT check_item FROM %s WHERE code = %s
```